# Include a Textbox inside a RadioButton

Tags: c#, textbox, radio-button

How would I include a TextBox in the middle of the text of a radio button?

For example; I want to have a radio button that says "Delay my shipment by X days"

The X in the above example would be a textbox that the user could enter in a value.

Comment: Is this WinForms / WPF / Web?

Comment: It's a web application actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to just separate the radio button text into several controls:

RadioButton1 Label1 TextBox1 Label2

**Where:**

- RadioButton1 has no text.
- Label1 Text = "Delay my shipment by "
- Label2 Text = " days"

**ASP:**

```
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="MyGroupName" runat="server" />
Delay my shipment by <asp:TextBox runat="server"  /> days.
```

Comment: and use JS/jQuery to enable/disable the textbox based on the radio button's value

Comment: @Brad - I'm not sure we know that the OP is asking about windows / forms / web.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Why not place the textbox after the radion button:
"Delay by no of days: X"

Comment: Perfectly valid; but the suits are adamant that it's displayed that way.